# How to convert values from 0: 270 to 0:1023 in Python?

Tags: python, arduino

Hi i need help with my script for Arduino with Python
I have python script it put out angle between 0-270
I need to convert this value to servo-read-able in meaning 0-1023
Can some one from community help me 
Thanks

Comment: As a new user, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, you said "convert", but you totally omitted the requirements that  this conversion has to fulfill. Generally, for mapping, you can use e.g. the `dict` type or maybe do so using a computation. It all depends on the requirements.

Comment: `proportion = 1023/270` (`3.788888888`) and then `270*proportion` gives `1023.0`

Answer (score 1):

So you just want to convert one number into another? Or the list of numbers? 
It sounds simple

```
new_angle = int(old_angle*3.78 )
```

3.78 # Because it's 1023/270

And then int() to convert to integer

Comment: you should add explanation why `3.78` (PL: powinnieneś wyjaśnić dlaczego `3.78`)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like the map function?
https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/ or https://processing.org/reference/map_.html

```
def maprange( a, b, s):
    (a1, a2), (b1, b2) = a, b
    return  b1 + ((s - a1) * (b2 - b1) / (a2 - a1))

maprange((0, 270), (0, 1023), value)
```

Taken from https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range#Python

I hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I And i have one more question.
I look on Internet but i cant find anything.
I work on quadruped robot i need some way if i stop my robot in some angle. Then i reboot him i get this position as home as 0,0 but i hook up on servo potenciometr. Is there any command in arduino to Updates servo posion by potenciometr value converted to angle but dont move the servo ex.[servo start: 0°,0°- now is on 70°,50° but it doest move] i hope you understood me